# Adjust child element height based on Parent height and Top position value value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having parent with fixed height (400px) and child div height more than parent div height (400px - child div's top value) should be based on below conditions.

- Parent div height - child div's top position value (Eg: 40px in this scenario)

So, Finally Child div height should be 360px (400px - child div's top value of -40px)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        Parent Height: <span id="parentHeight"></span><br>
        Distance from top: <span id="distanceFromTop"></span><br>
        Child Height: <span id="childHeight"></span><br>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Script:**

```
var __parentHeight = $('.parent').height();
var __distanceFromTop = $('.parent').offset().top - $('.child').offset().top;
var __finalHeight = parseInt(__parentHeight) - parseInt(__distanceFromTop);

$('#parentHeight').html(__parentHeight + 'px');
$('#distanceFromTop').html(__distanceFromTop + 'px');
$('#childHeight').html(__finalHeight + 'px');

$('.child').css('height', __finalHeight + 'px');
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ReddyPrasad/L6zxrhv9/26/)**

**Expected:**

[image]

**What I am getting is:**

[image]

Comment: Not sure why you are trying to convert the value into a jquery object but it should be `var __finalHeight = parseInt(__parentHeight) - parseInt(__distanceFromTop);`. This part makes no sense `$(__parentHeight)`

Comment: Try to log __finalHeight , you probably get NaN , so there is the problem

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I am getting *440px* as height instead of *360px*

Comment: One of the values is a negative value, thats why. Try `var __finalHeight = Math.abs(__parentHeight) - Math.abs(__distanceFromTop);`

Comment: *Thanks for the TIP* :)

Answer (score 0):

Update your final height calculation like that => `var __finalHeight = parseInt(__parentHeight) - parseInt(__distanceFromTop);`